# Link is cut after question mark in dynamic php table

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, varchar, sql-types

I have a PHP dynamic table, and when I click on one of my link (`http://www.xxxxxx.com/?r=xxxxxxxxx`), the link open in a new tab and it's cut after the question mark (`?`), like `www.xxxxxx.com/?`.

Here is the table php code:

```
echo '<div class="row"><tr>';
    echo '<td><form action='.$data['referral'].'>
        <input class="btn" type="submit" formtarget="_blank" value='.$data['webadress'].' data-value='.gmdate("H:i:s",($data['timer']*60+60)).' data-start="false"></form></td>';
    echo '<td>Now</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data['timer'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data['payout'].'</td>';
echo '</tr></div>';
```

In my database, the `$data['referral']` are my `www.xxxxxx.com/?r=xxxxxxxxx` link's.

I think is the type or something in my database option is wrong, so it cut after the question mark. Now I'm on `varchar(255)` and `latin1_general_ci`.

EDIT: I have put an input because I need store data for a timer, here is the JS:

```
$(window).load(function(){

        var row = document.getElementsByClassName("color");

        function toTimeString(seconds) {
                return (new Date(seconds * 1000)).toUTCString().match(/(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/)[0];
        }

        function redColor(element) {
                $(element).css('background-color', 'rgba(255,0,0,0.7)');
        }

        function normalColor(elemen) {
                $(element).css('background-color', 'transparent');
        }

        $('.btn').on('click', startTimer);

        function startTimer() {
                var dataStartElem = $(this);
                var dataStart = dataStartElem.attr('data-start');
                if (dataStart === 'false') {
                        dataStartElem.attr('data-start', 'true');
                        var nextElem = dataStartElem.parents('td').next();
                        var duration = dataStartElem.attr('data-value');
                        var a = duration.split(':');
                        var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
                        setInterval(function () {
                                seconds--;
                                if (seconds >= 0) {
                                        nextElem.html(toTimeString(seconds));
                                        redColor(nextElem);
                                }
                                if (seconds === 0) {
                                        nextElem.html('Now');
                                        dataStartElem.attr('data-start', 'false');
                                        clearInterval(seconds);
                                        normalColor(nextElem);
                                }
                        }, 1000);
                }
        }
});
```

This JS, start the timer and put it in red, and after the "now" appear when is finish.

Comment: put at the top of this code `var_dump($data);` and say what it shows

Comment: in the source code "in the browser" what is written inside action ?

Comment: (a) You are missing quotes around action attributes value  (in form ) and the value of the value attribute of input (b) in firebug check where the request URL . (this tells us if the form is being submitted to right page or not)

Comment: @gyaani_guy how to check the request_url ?

Comment: open chrome > press F12 > select network tab. Here you can see all requests details.
Now press any links, submit forms and explore there.
Firefox alternative would be firebug (extension)

Comment: @gyaani_guy Ok, and which thigs you want ? I have many font, style or script

Comment: For our purposes, doesn't matter, choose any. And check the request URL

Comment: @gyaani_guy i don't have any XHR purpose.

Answer (score 1):

As @Otto said, try to do it in way near to this:

```
echo '
<div class="row">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="' . htmlspecialchars($data['referral']) . '">' . htmlspecialchars($data['webadress']) . '</a>
        </td>
        <td>Now</td>
        <td>' . $data['timer'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $data['payout'] . '</td>
    </tr>
</div>
';
```

Comment: Thank for the reply, but it's the same problem, the link is still cut after the "?"

Comment: actually i dont see links here. only button. show more code

Comment: The link is the <form action='.$data['referral'].'> and in this data there is the link (maybe you can invite me in a chat and if we figured out i post the solution?)

Comment: thanks again but still same link problem. I think is in the database, don't you ?

Comment: i only need to know what contains $data['referral']. WHEN u ll give me that var_dump?

Comment: the var_dump is array(4) { ["webadress"]=> string(21) "http://xxxxxx.in/" ["timer"]=> string(3) "420" ["payout"]=> string(4) "2100" ["referral"]=> string(58) "http://xxxxx.in/?r=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" } so it the link in my db

Comment: url in new window should not be cutted. its not a database problem. certainly xxxx.com dont like this param ?r=xxxxxxxx and somehow redirects you

Comment: try to enter this adress in your browser. are still there where u suppose? i mean url

Comment: The new reply worked, but i dont have anymore all my data like time and other in it.that's why i need a input field. question update with the javascript

Comment: as i see no more pation to your question. i ll help you with it, but tomorrow.

Comment: thanks but i have already find a way. Look my reply it's worked with it. Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 1):

By using a GET form, you override the query part of the action. Either convert your form to a normal link, or put the query part of the URL in a hidden input.

Comment: it's a dynamic table, how to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution, thanks to all have help me to figured out: i think it's the form who dont take "?" on link, so i have changed it to a normal link and here we go.

```
echo '<div class="row">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="'.$data['referral'].'" target="_blank">
                <input type="submit" value="'.htmlspecialchars($data['webadress']).'" data-value="'.gmdate("H:i:s", ($data['timer'] * 60 + 60)).'" data-start="false" class="btn" formtarget="_blank">    
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>Now</td>
        <td>'.$data['timer'].'</td>
        <td>' . $data['payout'] . '</td>
    </tr>
</div>';
```